# Adobe Products and (actual) uses/overlaps:

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, adobe-after-effects, adobe-acrobat

### Adobe Products and (actual) uses/overlaps:

---

**Context:**

---

So as a "Beginner" when it comes to Adobe Products, I'm just starting out my testing and trying of the various Adobe Products. To be honest, I feel like there is quite a bit of overlap between the various products (maybe I'm wrong, I don't know really).

Currently, I use Adobe Indesign for making a newsletter, Photoshop primarily for removing backgrounds on JPEGs to make them PNGs (that's literally about it, really).

Now, before you go and tell me to look at the Adobe Website, I'm not really asking for a comprehensive "This app does this", but I'm more looking at the usefulness and overlaps:

---

**Question:**

---

What is each Adobe app used for, and do I need to really get them all?

**For example:**

> Does Premiere Pro do the same as Premiere Rush, or are there some niche differences?

> What is Adobe Lightroom for, and how is it different from Photoshop and Indesign?

> What is Adobe Lightroom Classic for, why does it have to be a separate app from Lightroom, and how is it different from Photoshop?

Which ones are the essentials to have? Which ones are unnecessary and frankly just have really niche applications? Which ones overlap?

#### The key ones I'm interested in:

- Photoshop
- Lightroom
- Lightroom Classic
- Indesign
- Premiere Pro
- Premiere Rush
- Illustrator
- XD
- After Effects
- Aero
- Fresco
- Dimension
- Dreamwaver
- Animate
- Acrobat

Comment: No one here knows *exactly* how you need to utilize software. You may only need Lightroom Classic and its features. On the other hand you may require Photoshop and its features because even Lightroom is not enough. You really **are** asking for a comprehensive list of Adobe software - seeking someone else to detail research you don't want to do yourself. Go to Adobe's site.. view Lightroom Classic features - would those allow you to do all you need to raster images? View Premier Rush features - would those allow you to do all you need for video? Users here can't determine this for you.

Comment: In addition, Adobe offers **free trials** so you are free to explore yourself.

Comment: 1. I'm not talking about how I need to utilise the software. I'm asking about the guide to which are seen as the essentials, which are niche, which have applications that can be done with other apps, etc. It doesn't matter how I need it, if Photoshop can do all the jobs of Lightroom (for example) then that is what I am asking. 2. Free Trials aren't what I'm looking for. You can't figure out an application and all of its uses and how that overlaps and get a judge of just how niche it is in a week or so. And besides - its far more time consuming than just getting an experienced "expert" opinion.

Comment: And @Scott with 176,000 reputation and nearly 3300 posts on Illustrator, Indesign and Photoshop, you are exactly the type of person I was hoping to get an answer from. I'm sure you know those 3 along with most of the other Adobe softwares extremely well and so your opinion is far more useful and qualified than that of a beginner going on to a trial and making a ton of assumptions. You've probably used these programs extensively and know which ones are worth it and which are frankly unnecessary. That's all I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It would be good if you could give some more information about what you are wanting to learn to do- photography, video, web design, illustration, 3D, animation, etc. and then ask a specific question about what apps the "experts" use for the tasks you want to learn.

Comment: Experts in different fields will give you different versions of what's essential and what's niche. The way you use Photoshop sounds like that's an unnecessarily app for you for example, but others spend the whole day in it. The question is too broad and will require an essai to make an attempt in answering it.

Comment: Fair enough - point taken. Is it ok to leave this question up though because answers have already been placed? Or is it going to be closed? (I can't see the close votes).

Comment: @Gill probably closed it has 4 votes. Anyway i find that lightroom is not a terribly good for you it creates too much reliance. Probably the only tool i can not really substitute with something equal or better is illustrator. I wouldnt rent lighteoom too risky.

Comment: @joojaa what is the point of closing a question with 2 long, detailed answers? Is it just me, or does that seem kinda useless?

Comment: To discourage behaviour that is unwanted. None of the answers ultimately answer the question asked as its asked, they answer the question behind the question. So the answers are not a good fit for what the site tries to achieve. A database of good curated questions with objective answers. Hence closure. You should have asked a different more enumerable question.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to point out that, unlike 15 years ago when you had to spend $500+ on DVDs (or the ridiculous 20+ 3.5" floppy discs 15 years before that), all these are **subscriptions**. You can *cancel or change* a subscription in a month if you feel something isn't working well for you.

If you intend to buy once and not be hindered by lack of features, then you merely want the *flagship* products.. - **Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign, Acrobat, Premier, After Effects**. All these come in the US$600/year subscription (typical individual pricing at this time, there may be student discount or other discounts available). With that price tag you actually **get access to everything else** as well, so the dilemma is sort of moot at that point.

The *only* reason to even consider avoiding the full $600/yr subscription is to save money, which I can fully understand. But, to that end, no one could possibly determine what *you* can and can not live without in terms of software features.

When considering anything print related, you'll probably need Illustrator, Acrobat, InDesign, and a raster image editor (Photoshop/Lightroom/Lightroom Classic) at a minimum.... the cost of individual independent subscriptions to those will *surpass* the price of the full "master collection" subscription.

Point being....

If you need **any** three or more of the Adobe apps... you might as well pay for the **full collection subscription**. It is actually more cost effective when paid yearly. There's **no point to feature comparisons at that point** because you'll have access to *every application Adobe offers* should you need it.

I completely detest the whole subscription model, but for beginners it's really a way to save thousands of dollars that used to be required. 
<sub>(You simply never "own" anything and Adobe will lock you out of your original, copyrighted, work files unless you continue paying them.)</sub>

---

Regarding the comparisons...

The thing is..... I know PS, AI, IND very well... but I have no clue about Lightroom.. because I've *always* had Photoshop... With Photoshop, Lightroom has no use. I could not possibly begin to state whether Lightroom, or Lightroom Classic, would fit anyone's needs. Especially without a detailed description of those needs.

The best I could offer would be hierarchy which is really just my **opinion** about the software based entirely upon **my needs**, not yours..

- Photoshop is more robust (more features, broader feature abilities) than Lightroom, which is more robust than Lightroom Classic. If you have Photoshop, you don't need any Lightroom version.
- Illustrator, Acrobat, and InDesign have no equal in the Adobe stable, they are unique. If you need PDF editing, you need Acrobat. If you wish to create vector artwork, you need Illustrator. If you plan on doing multi-page layouts, you need InDesign. There's no way around these really. Yes you may able to scrape by with using Illustrator for a 4-page layout.. Or InDesign for some vector artwork... you can pound in a nail with a screwdriver... that doesn't mean it's easier or the way you'll always want to do it.
- I don't do video.. so no clue about Premier, After Effects, etc
- I prefer a robust text editor (BBEdit) to Dreamweaver. I've always hated Dreamweaver.
- I don't honestly know what Aero and Fresco are.
- I don't do much animation so Animate isn't necessary here.
- I'm aware of UX and Dimension.. simply haven't needed them here, personally.

So you can see my experience may not really be in line with your needs or plans. What I think is right is really only "right" or "best" if you are doing remarkably similar work as me at the same relative proficiency. That match is very rare among *any* two people in the field. Someone else with the same number years experience I have may offer a *completely* different opinion.

All in all, really, only you can do the research as it relates to your needs. You can see the "group" of apps as they relate to work. i.e. Photoshop, Lightroom, Lightroom classic = Raster image editors --- Premier, Premier Rush, After Effects = Video editing. etc. So you pick the one with features you need.

---

Comment: Lightroom (Classic) are very different beasts from Photoshop. As a graphic artist, you’ll probably use PS and rarely need to bother with opening LR; as a photographer, there’s a good chance you’ll have LR open always and rarely need to bother with PS. Photoshop is not the tool for comparing and selecting shots, applying RAW changes to multiple images, etc. Camera RAW in Photoshop works (and even has a few features mysteriously missing from LR), but as an organisational tool, it’s useless. (Also, I think you mean LR Classic is more robust than LR, which is still more limited.)

Comment: Goes to my point about one person not having the knowledge to blindly state what's "best" for anyone else @JanusBahsJacquet -- clearly I don't have a broad understanding of Lightroom versions `:)` Truth is.. I haven't seen LR since it was initially released and I determined it wasn't necessary in **my** workflows.

Answer (score 1):

I use Acrobat, Illustrator, InDesign, Photoshop, and Lightroom. I consider these to be the core programs- but really they are only *my* core programs. The other programs I do not use- but may become interested in at some point as I do have the subscription.

For me, Lightroom is very necessary in addition to Photoshop. Lightroom has a great cataloging/ organizing structure to store and catalog all your photos in one place. This is important to someone who takes a lot of photos. Photoshop simply does not have this capability. Lightroom also has enough editing/ adjusting functions to make your photos very "show-able". Photoshop goes very much deeper with it's ability to manipulate images.  Lightroom is like your "box of photos" which you can organize, adjust, manipulate, sort, keyword, group, and share- then when you want to make something special you take a photo out of that box and bring it into Photoshop to do final editing/ adjusting (and much more).

Lightroom Classic is the version I use. It is desktop based so your photos are stored on your hard drive (or several of them). Lightroom CC is a newer cloud based version and you can store your pics on the cloud so you can access them from anywhere. Lightroom CC also has a mobile app with limited features. Lightroom Classic has a few more features than Lightroom CC but the CC version is catching up to the Classic version.

I think there is only any overlap in the "full" version of a program and it's "lighter" version (Premier Rush versus Premier Pro for example). Typically the "full" version will have a lot more features but be a lot more complex to learn as well. More than any overlap, I find the Adobe programs have a great deal of compatibility with each other- they work well together (usually). You can make an asset in Illustrator or Photoshop and bring it directly into InDesign. Or place a .psd file into Illustrator in its native .psd format then edit it in Photoshop if needed and it will update in Illustrator.

All this to say, learn the programs that get you the knowledge and the proper tools to do what you want to do.

Comment: Would I be making a crude analogy to compare Lightroom to the Mac (/iOS) Photos app? Or is it far more advanced @Kyle?

Comment: My first thought was that no, the Photos app is nothing like Lightroom- but in fact you are correct- both are organizational and editing tools for your photos. Lightroom is far more advanced in all areas- with far more control but also a far steeper learning curve. And it costs $. I would say that Photos is more of an entry level app while Lightroom is a professional level program. And yet, there may be Pros who solely use the Photos app- although it is hard for me to imagine. Again, this is all my opinion but I am confident that any research you do on this will confirm what I am saying

Answer (score 1):

Let us answer the question more objectively. So your asking why do software have overlapping feature sets? The answer is simply that they are trying to solve a problem  that is relatively close to the other problem and need to be compatible with other software to some extent.

Ok, so you so specifically asked why Adobe does this? Well this implies that a company is one entity. Adobe is not, except in legal fiction. In reality its just a collection of people who have contradictory goals. So it starts to make more sense at this point it goes something like this:

Different elements of adobe design a product. Since there is a general consensus at adobe that products should be as compatible as possible most software will use one of the internal libraries (one is called PDF kit that powers illustrator and indesign, and is used by Photoshop, after effects...). Since the goal is interoperability some of the basic features leak over. Its really standardisation like PDF and SVG specification that are driving things here, because without such effort you couldn't share anything.

Anyway this does not imply overlap as such, it just means you see a feature as overlap. In reality there is less overlap than you think. Take some examples:

- There is no application in the suite that can take illustrators job. Yes im aware that some people do similar stuff in photoshop and inDesign. But still critical vector design tools are missing in these apps. And using photoshop for vectors is a huge mistake in many cases. So you can only really mistake the overlaps if you dont really understand the subject well.
- After effects is not a substitute for premiere. In fact after effects sucks at video editing. Yeah it can do it, because without such capability it couldnt do its primary function.
- Photoshop does not overlap with lightroom. Lightroomvis designed for curating of images, during and after a photoshoot. Photoshop can not do this job. Photoshop is meant for final publication of one image with possibly design elements on the image itself.

*....

So to all intents the overlaps are because of compatibility and similarish scope. But only on a casual level.